# WebLogic 12c ClassCastException when Using JPA

Tags: java, jpa, weblogic12c, entitymanager, classcastexception

We are currently migrating our Java EE application from Weblogic 11g to Weblogic 12c.

Here were are facing ClassCastException when using JPA EntityManager's query.getSingleResult() method.

It seems to be the Object returned by entityManager is loaded by different classloader and the Object in Application is loaded by different classloader were the classes are same.

While checking with **wls-cat** in weblogic it shows Same classloader with multiple instance for single application.

Error: Caused By: java.lang.ClassCastException: Cannot cast com.dev.user.dataaccess.jpa.entity.User to com.dev.user.dataaccess.jpa.entity.User

Can someone help me to resolve it? Thanks in Advance.

[image: added wls-cat classloader image]

**UPDATED:** After some workaround found that Persistence.XML is loaded on Application deployement so entitymanager loads the classes declared in persistnce.xml . When we redeploy our application uses new classloader but entitymanager still uses the old classloader.

Comment: How have you deployed the application and what is in its packaging? Ie do you have  the JPA provider jars in the application and on the server multiple times? Do you use hot redeployment, and if so, does restarting the server help?

Comment: We are using EAR for deployment. Yes we do have JPA jars. No We not do hot redeployement.

Comment: More meant where the jars are and if any are included in the ear that might also be on the server's class path.